# C# delete tagged Object

Tags: c#, winforms, tags

I have a question regarding use of "Tag" :

I have a ListBox, or ListView, in which I have the name of my objects, I added a "Tag" property to find its corresponding object :

```
foreach(Operation op_ass in ListOpAss1)
{
    op_ass.getNom(Properties.Settings.Default.Langue);
    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(op_ass.Nom);
    item.Tag = op_ass;
    listBoxAss1.Items.Add(op_ass.Nom);
}
```

Now what I would like, is when I select an item in my list(or several), make an action on corresponding objects. But how can I find them back?
For example I want to remove selected objects from a List, or get the list of Operation ID (without displaying ID in my list).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are adding the property, `op_ass.Nom` into the listbox instead of the ListViewItem, `item`. Modify your code as follows:

```
foreach (Operation op_ass in ListOpAss1)
   {
       op_ass.getNom(Properties.Settings.Default.Langue);
       ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(op_ass.Nom);
       item.Tag = op_ass;

       // Add the list view item instead of op_ass.Nom
       listBoxAss1.Items.Add(item);
   }
```

Now you should be able to retrieve the tag from selected item/items as follows:

```
var operation = ((listBox1.SelectedItem as ListViewItem).Tag) as Operation;
```

Alternatively, you could think of using data binding as follows:

```
 foreach (Operation op_ass in ListOpAss1)
   {
      op_ass.getNom(Properties.Settings.Default.Langue);
   }

 listBoxAss1.DataSource = ListOpAss1;
 listBoxAss1.DisplayMember = "Nom";
```

And access the data bound object as follows:

```
var operation = listBox1.SelectedItem as Operation;
```

Comment: Working perfectly, thanks. Just for taking back selected item, your syntax is not working, I just put this : var operation = listBoxAss1.SelectedItem as Operation; and working as a charm, Tag is not even needed as my listBox contains all the object :)

Comment: You're welcome.. :) If you use data binding, then the latter way of casting is the way to go..the former one (casting to ListViewItem) won't work with data binding

Comment: sorry, didn't notice the last line, well anyway thanks you solved my problem :)

Answer (score -1):

using foreach is kind of deprecated you can look into implemented functions in list of objects

```
ListOpAss1.ForEach(x=> 
{
    x.getNom(Properties.Settings.Default.Langue);
    var item = new ListViewItem(x.Nom);
    item.Tag = x;
    listBoxAss1.Items.Add(x.Nom);
});
```

in order to select an item in a list you can use SingleOrDefalt() or Skip(count) take (count) for multiple files or you can run native querys with conditions to search the list like this

```
var items = collection.Where(x=> x.City == "Burgas").ToList(); //You can use select if you want only certain properties of the object to be selected
///then you can use that new item list to remove the objects from the collection list like this
items.ForEach(x=> 
{
    collection.Remove(x);
});
```

Comment: "using foreach is kind of deprecated".  Say what?  No.  No it isn't.

Comment: Your answer does not solve the problem.  You've just rewritten it in a new, equally erroneous, way.  Like the code in question, you never actually add the `item` to anything.

Comment: Well using the implemented ForEach on list<T> is much more efficient and saves some space, after all why do people at Microsoft make new implementations if they're not to be used over the old way.Keeps the code much smaller and redable.(that's what I meant under deprecated, not that its not used...I rarely use it but everyone can do whatever he wants after all)

Comment: I'm afraid "new" != "better".  But you are correct that it's a personal preference.  Had you not called it deprecated, I would have left it at that.

Comment: It does not yes, because he has an error in his code, didn't see that in the morning but generally he would get an runtime error when he tries to insert anything in a collection that he is foreaching

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but I don't understand why you say foreach is depreciated? and why using qlink?(excuse me if didn't spell it good), I see more and more people using it, is it much faster than foreach?